# Why is pointing to one before the first element of an array not allowed in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In C, a pointer is allowed to point to any element of an array, as well as to one past the last element of the array; pointing to beyond this is undefined behavior (C11 standard, §6.5.6, paragraph 8).

However, why is pointing to one before the first element of an array not similarly allowed?

P.S: I know that, in order to circumvent the above restriction, one can sometimes declare an array 1 unit larger than needed, then use only positions from 1 on to store elements, and finally leave position 0 just as a guarantee that traversing the array backwards will be safe. However, sometimes we must use an array as given, and then the problem of pointing to one before the first element remains.

Comment: I guess it was just one of these design decision that were taken for the "why not?" reason.

Comment: As far as I know, pointing beyond the last element isn't inherently an error either. I mean using clang, I can run `int main (void) { int hi[3] = {1, 2, 3}; printf("%d", hi[9]); }` and it will just point to the spot of memory that is 9 * sizeof(int) right of the current position. Some runners have safeguards against this and will throw an error if unallocated memory is accessed, but that depends on your platform.

Comment: @user2662833: Your code is undefined behavior, and so is pointing to one before the beginning of an array.  Such code can't be trusted to do (or not do) anything.

Comment: @user2662833 I guess the question here is about pointer arithmetic rules, which state that if a result of such an arithmetic is a pointer outside an object or one element past it's end, the behavior is undefined. It i not even talking about dereferencing.

Comment: @user2662833 Your example invokes undefined behavior. "Seems to work fine" is one form of undefined behavior. For example, if there happens to be a variable there at `hi[9]` and you modify it by an array out of bounds access, the compiler is free to assume that the array is not modified (even though you just did that) and optimize the code accordingly, leading to very strange bugs.

Comment: @EugeneSh., I understand that traversing an array backwards is (much) less common than doing it forwards, but it is useful nevertheless. Since it is a matter of symmetry, it surprises me that this is not allowed in the language.

Comment: Yep I realise it's undefined behaviour; but I'm just stating that it won't cause an error on all systems. Basically, any area outside the three allocated ints isn't guaranteed to contain anything in particular.

Comment: @user2662833 if it would cause error on all systems, it wouldn't be *undefined* behavior.

Comment: @PabloM.S.Farias what if you end up with negative value? (fairly improbable, I know)

Comment: A one-past-last pointer points to the byte right next after the last byte of the array. A one-before-first pointer would point to `sizeof element`th byte before the first byte of the array. Arrays may be located at the very beginning of memory or segment, so your pointer subtraction will overflow and comparisons will be off. In order to prevent that you would have to reserve an entire element worth of bytes, which is not acceptable as far as C goes. You can decide you want an extra element and declare the array accordingly, but C won't force it on you.

Comment: Seg faults etc is not the only problem that out of bounds could cause. Example: `int array[2]; int x=0; array[2] = 1; if(x!=0) { do_stuff(); }`. The compiler is free to optimize away the call to `do_stuff()` since it can deduce that `x` was never changed by your program. Even if `array[2]` happened to actually write to the memory location of `x`. This is because `array` does not alias `x`, the compiler will regard them as unrelated variables. GCC in particular is known to often make such assumptions.

Comment: For the compiler it's quite easy to add a bit of headroom or alignment at the end of an array to allow beyond-limits-access. It is relatively impossible to do the same at the beginning (as the first element of the array may be required to use the first address of an enclosing data structure or even at the beginning of an allocated page)

Comment: @n.m. Your comment is worthy of an answer - very good reasoning.

Comment: One can also approach the asymmetry this way. A pointer points to the beginning (the first byte) of an object, not to its end. Incrementing a pointer is akin to sweeping it across the pointed-to object. A symmetric construct would be an anti-pointer that points to the last byte of an object. But we don't really need this: instead of an anti-pointer we can use `pointer+1` that points to the beginning of the next object, or one byte past the end of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topic "a pointer is allowed to point to any element of an array" has been part of the C language for a very long time; it can already be found in the [ANSI-C standard / C89](http://read.pudn.com/downloads133/doc/565041/ANSI_ISO%2B9899-1990%2B[1].pdf) (cf. section 6.3.6 Additive operators, page 46f), which already mentions that within this range implementations must prevent arithmetic overflows. Therein, at the end of page 47, one can also find a footnote that explains the rational behind it:

> Another way to approach pointer arithmetic is to first convert the
>   pointer(s) to character pointers: In this scheme the integral
>   expression added to or subtracted from the converted pointer is first
>   multiplied by the size of the object originally pointed to and the
>   resulting pointer is converted back to the original type. For pointer
>   subtraction the result of the difference between the character
>   pointers is similarly divided by the size of the object originally
>   pointed to.
>
> **When viewed in this way, implementations need only provide one extra
>   byte (which may overlap another object in the program) just after the
>   end of the object in order to satisfy the "one past the last element"
>   requirement**.

Therefrom we may deduce that the reason is preventing arithmetic overflows, which an implementation *must* avoid in the range of an array and one past (but which obviously *does not need to be guaranteed* for an element one before the first element of an array).

Why not one before - is probably (I have no proof for that) connected with the fact that pointers ranges could be limited to particular memory segments, and placing objects at the begin of a memory segment together with arithmetics like "one before the first element" could lead to an overflow. I'd say statement  *"implementations need only provide one extra byte (which may overlap another object in the program) just after the end of the object"* is a clear indicator supporting this assumption, as the standard at this time explicitly addressed the "one extra byte"-topic at the end but did not suggest something similar for the begin of memory segments.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that it's the rationale, but in practice you would need to either

- throw away the relational operators on pointers (due to wraparound), or
- require that no objects of size X be stored at an address less than X, or
- cut the available memory in half (due to negative addresses).

Neither option is very pleasant.

Answer (score 2):

The rationale why it is allowed to point one past the array in the first place, is to enable certain kinds of "C++/STL-ish" programming patterns:

```
int array [n] = ...;
int* begin = array;
int* end = array + n;

for(int* i=begin; i!=end; i++)
...
```

For situations like the one above it makes sense to point one item past the array. But of course it does not make sense to actually access that item - which would be undefined behavior.

So the above is a special case. However, there exists no situation where it makes sense to point one item *before* the array.

Comment: No common situation, you can easily contrive to come up with some situation in which it makes some amount of sense.

Comment: @pvg Not really, since the memory layout is only guaranteed to be contiguous for arrays (not guaranteed for structs etc). The only time it would make sense to access one item before would be a 2D array, but then you'd rather do that by accessing the last item of the previous array, instead of the "[-1]" index.

Comment: This pattern was invented way before C++ or STL, and most probably will stay here long after C++ and STL both hit the dustbin of history.

Comment: It would be possible to write a loop that iterates in reverse over elements of an array, in which case (to use the same loop construct) the end pointer would be one before the start of the array.   However, use cases involving iterating over an array in reverse order are less common than iterating forward.

Comment: You can just switch the direction of traversal of your own example.

Comment: And maybe that's a good thing that we can't iterate backwards. Because I'm not so sure that backwards iteration would necessarily be as effective as forwards iteration, as far as cache memories go.

Comment: Oh btw, the backwards version of the above is _not_ `for(int* i=end; i!=begin; i--)` but rather `for(int* i=end-1; i!=begin-1; i--)`. Why you would have a need to write such ugly code is not obvious. This whole pattern can always be replaced with an integer offset too.

Comment: @Lundin, please consider the following code: `for (int *i = array + n - 1; array <= i; --i) ...`. I understand that this is not the backwards version of the loop you mentioned in your answer. However, it is (in my opinion) a perfectly useful backwards loop.

Comment: Backwards loops are not uncommon, expecially when managing lists.

Comment: Your caches example is just begging the question. Caches tend to work like that because sequential forward access is a common and important case. Your claim is that there is _no_ situation the reverse could possibly be useful and that's just not the true. This is largely a matter of convenience and supporting typical use, not some inherent computational principle.

Comment: A loop up from 0 to 'SomeList.length-1' will fail if some code in the loop deletes the item at the current index, (maybe it matches some search criterion), because the loop will run off the end of the now-shorter list.  A loop down from 'SomeList.length-1' to 0 is safe in that scenario because the end index, (0), does not change during the loop - the next index is always valid even if the current item is deleted.