# Unexpected output in C program when printing

Tags: c, output, printf

Assuming that all the header files are included.

```
void main() { 
int i; 
clrscr(); 
printf("india"-'A'+'B'); 
getch(); }
```

**The Output of the following function is : `ndia`**

Can anyone please explain me this output?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic.  Why don't you explain what you are expecting?

Comment: The expression `"india"-'A'+'B'` does not make any sense at all

Comment: @klutt Seems more like a trick question on a quiz or something similar. Designed to confuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int printf(const char *restrict format, ...);
```

When you do `format - 'A' + 'B'` , it's equal to `format + 1` considering the ASCII values of `A` and `B`.

`format` is the base address and when you do `format + 1` it points to second memory location of this character string and from there it starts printing which is `ndia`.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `"india"-'A'+'B'` does not make sense in any sane code. But it will (but see below) result in a pointer to the second element, because `'B' - 'A'` will evaluate to `1`.

However, the subexpression `"india"-'A'` will invoke undefined behavior, because the resulting pointer will point outside the array. This is explained here: [Why is pointing to one before the first element of an array not allowed in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46199653/6699433)

If we rewrite a bit and add parenthesis: `"india"+('B'-'A')` the expression is well defined and equal to `"india" + 1`

Comment: expression `printf("india"-('A'+'B'))` is pointing to **"india"-131** ASCII of{A(65)+B(66)} and there is no output of this expression `"india"-('A'+'B')` .                                                    But Expression `printf("india"+(-'A'+'B'))` prints Out: **ndia**

Comment: @AdityaMishra Don't know why my comment disappered, but thanks. I have adressed those issues.