# Reverse iterators and negative strided iterators in C++, using one before beginning as sentinel

Tags: c++, reverse-iterator

In [Another way of looking at C++ reverse iterators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211112-00/?p=105908) Raymond Chen wrote:

> ... a quirk of the C++ language: You are allowed to have a pointer
> "one past the end" of a collection, but you are not allowed to have a
> pointer "one before the beginning" of a collection.

I understand that it probably means "undefined behavior" and that is pretty much a conversation ender. But **I am curious what is the worst that can happen in a realistic system if one ignores this rule. A segmentation fault? an overflow of pointer arithmetic? unnecessary paginations?**

Remember that the pointer "before" the beginning (like "end") is not supposed to be referenced either, the problem seem to have the pointer just *trying* to point to it.

The only situation I can imagine it can be a problem is with a system where memory location "0" is valid.
But even then, if that is so there are bigger problems, (e.g. nullptr would be problematic in itself too and wrapping around might still work by convention I guess.)

I am not questioning the implementation of `reverse_iterator` with an off-by-one special code.
The question occurred to me because if you have a generic implementation of "strided" iterator would require a special logic for negative strides and that has a cost (in code and at runtime).

Arbitrary strides, including negative ones could be naturally appearing with multidimensional arrays.
I have a multidimensional array library in which I always allowed negative strides in principle, but now I realized that they should have a special code (different from the positive case) if I allowed them at all and I don't want to expose undefined behavior.

Comment: *"worst that can happen"* An optimizer getting confused and doing weird things. Or getting a weird crash and having to wonder if it's caused by this UB or not.

Comment: [The LLVM Project Blog - What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior #1/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) ie what the compiler can do to you.  It's not just seg fault;, the compiler can remove / change / "go strange" when it decides that a brance of code contains UB.

Comment: And also [Old New Thing - Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633) ie Worry about runtime errors but also worry that the compiler is going to change your code into something that you didn't intend.

Comment: The Ariane may explode or the mission to Mars fails and there are many casualties. Meaning, software can no longer be considered as safe in any way.

Comment: General concerns for undefined behavior aside, I don't think anything bad can happen in this instance on a modern machine (with a flat memory model and 2's complement arithmetic). The reason is that the compiler cannot (in general) prove that a pointer points at the start of an allocation. It might point in the middle. And in that case ```ptr[-1]``` is valid. So it doesn't make too much sense for the compiler to go haywire.

Comment: @Homer512 yes, that was my logic too. Granted i don’t use negative strides that much and they are not throughly tested but so far i never had a problem. it seems that a compiler will have to look at this special case to “make it not work”, almost on purpose. i believe other that yes a compiler has the right to go crazy but it will have to do it by going beyond a certain level of strictness.

Comment: @Homer512 maybe in the same way that C++ now accepts that ints are two’s complement, it can also accept that pointers are also arithmetically two’s complements. perhaps that will help to always have a well defined value for one before beginning and (together with null ptr) a well defined one past end value without wasting a single byte.  but who knows, there could be very strange address spaces out there.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46201372/7571258) suggests that the rationale behind this is historical - to prevent arithmetic overflow in case of [segmented memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I am curious what is the worst that can happen in a realistic
> system if one ignores this rule. A segmentation fault? an overflow of
> pointer arithmetic? unnecessary paginations?

Wasted space.

To be able to form the address "one before" you need to have the space available. For example, if you have a 1k struct, it must start at least 1k from the beginning of memory. On a small device with limited memory, or an x86 with segmented memory, that can be tricky.

To form a "one past" pointer/iterator you only need one byte beyond the end. As it cannot be dereferenced anyway, there is no need to have space for an entire object, just the possibility to form the address.

---

From the comments:

At the time the rules were defined, we had real CPUs with dedicated address registers that validated the address against the segment size on register load. That made sure that a -1 address would trap...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_68000#Architecture

This ruled out the case of having "one before" wrapping around to the end of the segment. Because if the segment is small, the resulting end might not be there.

Comment: that i guess is the question, the address doesn’t need to even exist because it is never referenced. it could be 2^64-1 for that matter which doesn’t exist in a big computer either.

Comment: but i get your point. one can imagine a physical addressing system in which a physical object has to be in a certain position even if not read. and this is not protected by some special guard (e.g.modulo arithmetic). this might be the origin of the rule actually, in a physical tape is not a good solution to say that the end is one before the beginning or any other point for that mater. the tape would be jumping around just to signal this.

Comment: @alfC - At the time the rules were defined, we had real CPUs with dedicated address registers that validated the address against the segment size on register load. That made sure that a -1 address would trap... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_68000#Architecture

Comment: That seems to be a very compeling reason to define the C abstract machine the way it is. (to cover this cases). I have the impression that the abstract machine would have to be changed significantly for new system that don't care about invalid addresses. I realize that my problem no only applies to negative strides by also to strides that do not divide the original allocated range either so, in my library I am going to warn against both cases but say that it "maybe" undefined behavior, which technically is undefined behavior but in practice means "know your target hardware".